# Laravel: Perform reduce functions on groupBy

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array of 'items' which has properties like 'supplier' and 'price'. It looks this(I expanded the last object so you can see the entire structure):
[image]

I have the results as I want them, but I feel that I am using an inefficient method.

```
private function generateSupplierDate(Collection $collection, array $suppliers = []): Collection
{
        $supplierGroups = $collection->pluck('items')->flatten()->whereIn('supplier', $suppliers)->groupBy('supplier')->values();

        $results = [];

        foreach ($supplierGroups as $suppliers) {
            $cost = 0;
            $name = '';
            foreach ($suppliers as $supplier) {
                $name = $supplier->supplier;
                $cost += $supplier->quantity;
            }
            array_push($results, ['name' => $name, 'cost' => $cost]);
        }

        return $results;

}
```

My goal is to get this but more efficiently:

```
[
  {
    supplier: 'Walmart',
    totalCost: 1000
  },
  {
    supplier: 'Bestbuy'
    totalCost: 100
   }
]
```

I tried to use reduce but that didn't seem to give me the right solution. And honestly, I'm a Javascript developer and I could do this in the Frontend, but that seems inefficient.

Any help would be appreciated (very new to Laravel/PHP).

Comment: Instead of relying on anonymous untyped associative arrays, consider creating classes for each level in the array. That way you can attach behavior to it, for instance sum() methods.

Comment: @ajthinking You'll have to show me, I'm quite new to OOP (been a FE developer forever now).